# Create sub-domain on public url or IP for AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have hosted my wordpress multisite on my amazon instance `ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` and the main site is showing on my IP `**.**.***.*` or public url , the sub-sites I wanted to show in sub domain so I have created the hosted on ec2 instance like

```
ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
india.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
saudi.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
canada.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

or on IP like below

```
**.**.***.*
india.**.**.***.*
saudi.**.**.***.*
canada.**.**.***.*
```

So how can I use sub-domains on IP or public-url, I have added sub-domains to my `hosts` file and also added the virtual hosts for the same.

Note: I can add DNS to the domain hosting and host like `domain.com, india.domain.com,saudi.domain.com,canada.domain.com` but I wanted to use on IP or public URL of AWS instance.

hosts files:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1  **.**.**.* india.**.**.**.* saudi.**.**.**.* canada.**.**.**.*
127.0.0.1 ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com india.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com canada.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com saudi.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Virtual host added for all regional sites

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName india.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  ServerAlias india.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

similarly added the virtual host for other sites canada and saudi and apart from this DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" will be same for all the site as I am making wordpress multisite.

Comment: let me know If you anyone needs more details.

Comment: What is the final url you want to use for the Canada site for example? Can you post your hosts file?

Comment: @RodrigoM For canada the final URL will be canada.ec2-**-**-***-*.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: You cannot do that. You can't modify the DNS of the domain amazonaws.com. Why don't you use a domain like canada.example.com?

Comment: I am wondering if I can do with the aws instance public URL or with IP.

Comment: No, you cannot modify any DNS record for the amazonaws.com domain.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do that. You can't modify the DNS of the domain `amazonaws.com`. This is the AWS domain for all AWS services, and it does not allow for any customer DNS records.

Comment: Can we add to IP??

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Add what to IP?

Comment: I mean ec2 instance Elastic IP address.

Comment: Yes you can assign an EIP to the instance

Comment: IMHO the proper DNS set up for wp multisite is an wild card DNS record so all subdomains point to the instance eg `*.example.com  IN A x.x.x.x`  where you point all subdomains to the EIP of the instance.